# I am using ngx bootstrap 2.0.3 datepicker and i see a warning message in console

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

BsDatepickerModule is under development, BREAKING CHANGES are possible,PLEASE, read changelog.

Is the datepicker module really expecting any breaking changes or is it stable to be used.

Comment: You should read their release documents for such information. A development release for testing purposes only and should not be used in production code

Comment: there is nothing mentioned about breaking changes in the release notes [here is link to release notes](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/releases/tag/v2.0.3) @NitishkumarSingh

Comment: Breaking changes are mentioned in [v2.0.0-beta.10](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.10) but 2.0.3 is a stable release

Comment: yes, but it's still in development branch. It hasn't been pushed to master branch in github repo